# How to print each rich text box to a4 page in winform application using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I am working on WYSIWYG kind of desktop application. I have ten rich text box in my application. Each contain formatted text. There is a button clicking upon the button, it should print and I am stuck here.

I want to print each rich text box content to a4 page. One way I found is to create image of the rich text box and print to a4 page but the problem is, I have ten rich text box and ten different printed file(PDF) are creating. But my goal is, the final print document should contain ten pages and each page should look exactly like rich text box content in the application.

Please guide me.

Comment: Creating images of controls is not a good idea *(at least when you intent to print them)*. There were already many users, that complained, that it seems good on monitor, but terrible on paper. And since you did not provide any source code, how you print, there is nothing anyone tell you how to improve your printing method. Sett [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print?view=netframework-4.7.2) example how to print on multiple pages.

Comment: Hi Julo, Thanks for response. I am aware of draw string and e.hasmorepages but problem with draw string, the text in the rich text box are formatted text. In this approach they loose the formatting. In MS WORD, it has multiple pages with text. And when user prints, it remains same in the printed document also. I want that output.

Comment: I know that the formatted text is something different. Make a correct printer class is another matter. But in the example you can see how to print multiple pages in one document. In your case you can change the print text to draw bitmap function for each page.